# problem: Unresolved attribute reference 'register_next_step_handler' for class 'Dispatcher'

Tags: aiogram

```py
elif message.text == "awf":
        message = await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "wegw4")
        await dp.register_next_step_handler(message, start_2)
```

I just started studying aiogram today, so I can't even suggest how to solve this problem